# Meteor - Get plain username & password on server when user tries to login

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to authenticate user login from some 3rd Party Api with same login credentials in case the login on Meteor fails.

I have tried to check for the username & password in **Accounts.validateLoginAttempt**, but it is not providing me the credentials which user just input from web app or mobile app.

Is there any work around to get plain username and password in that case?

Comment: Just to confirm the workflow here: your user logs in to your Meteor app using the Meteor `Accounts` passwort login (`Meteor.loginWithPassword`) and if it fails you want to use the very same credentials and retry the login but with a 3rd party API?

Comment: @Jankapunkt Exactly. You got it right. I want to achieve this on server side.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you need it to solve on the server?

Comment: Another question: is the 3rd party API a valid OAuth2 provider which is integrated into Meteor like `accounts-facebook` or `accounts-twitter`?

Comment: @Jankapunkt No its simle php based web service api

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yes because I currently do not have access to live apps, so I want to change the flow directly without re-uploading apps.

Comment: I suggest you post this question over on the Meteor forum https://forums.meteor.com/